# Scala: is there a try except in scala?

Tags: scala, exception

In Python I can do the following:

```
try{
 something
}
except{
whoops that didn't work, do this instead 
}
```

and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do this very same thing in Scala. I'm seeing a lot of ways to catch exceptions, but I haven't seen a way to ignore the exception and do something else.

Edit:

So here's what I tried in Scala:

```
try{ 
 something
}
catch{
 case ioe: Exception => something else
}
```

But it doesn't seem to like it...

Comment: How python's `try ... except` is different from scala's `try ... catch`? You want to handle all exceptions or just some particular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any reasons why scala's try-catch doesn't fit your needs:

```
scala> val foo = 0
foo: Int = 0

scala> val bar = try { 1 / foo } catch { case _: Exception => 1 / (foo + 1) } 
bar: Int = 1
```

Comment: Oh, I think I know what's happening. I'm using a specific case, but you're generalizing it. Yes?

Comment: @Shelby.S yes, I'm using generalized version, but specific case should work fine, as long as it corresponds to the exception: `catch { case _: java.lang.ArithmeticException => ... }` in the above code should work as well.

Comment: Thanks! I think this was my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some free advertising for `scala.util.Try`, which has additional facilities, not the least of which is that scalac will not harass you about a catch-all:

```
scala> try { ??? } catch { case _ => }
<console>:11: warning: This catches all Throwables. If this is really intended, use `case _ : Throwable` to clear this warning.
              try { ??? } catch { case _ => }
                                       ^

scala> import scala.util._
import scala.util._

scala> Try { ??? } map (_ => 1) recover { case _ => 0 } foreach (v => Console println s"Done with $v")
Done with 0
```